# download unexpected file when run npm install

Tags: node.js

when I run npm install karma, my node_modules download a lot of unexpected files. I dont want to upload so many not related file to git.
when I run something like npm install angular, it will only download the file of angular, which is what I want.

may I know is there any config I need to do to fix it? thanks.

screenshot of my node_modules folder:

[image]

Thanks all for your reply. below is my package.json 

is there any solution other than ignore these files? 

there are too many, not just the one on screenshot. 

And when I run npm install -g karma, I won't see these files

>

```
 {
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "description": "app: An Ionic project",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
    "karma": "^0.13.19",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    "android"
  ],
  "browser": {
    "localforage": "./node_modules/localforage/dist/localforage.js",
    "moment": "./node_modules/moment/moment.js",
    "sjcl": "./node_modules/sjcl/sjcl.js",
    "PouchDB": "./node_modules/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.js"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "localforage": "localforage",
    "moment": "moment",
    "sjcl": "sjcl",
    "PouchDB": "PouchDB"
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you add `node_modules/` to `.gitignore` ?

Comment: and Karma should only be a dev dependency

Comment: Can you post your package.json file?

Answer (score 0):

These are probably modules which are sub modules of karma or some other module you are using.

If you don't want it in git, you can just ignore them by adding them to the [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file. In fact, you should probably add the entire node_modules folder to the file.